# How can I get Pinax's OpenID to work with NAT?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, django, deployment

I have a Pinax gunicorn deployment behind a NAT, where the outward-facing Apache server does a ReverseProxy to the gunicorn server. Overall it works well but when I try to log in with OpenID I get an error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /openid/register/.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

How can I get Pinax to cooperate with NAT?

Comment: `Reason: Error reading from remote server` - this means that probably your application code either didn't return something in time or did return something wrong

Comment: Check the log files on both servers? Specific error codes? Try sniffing the traffic?